# Redis support in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, terraform, amazon-elasticache

I am not sure what I am doing something wrong here but the documentation does not say anything. I am trying to deploy a redis cluster but this is the error that I am getting:

```
aws_elasticache_cluster.cluster: engine "redis" does not support num_cache_nodes > 1
```

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/elasticache_cluster.html#num_cache_nodes) states for `num_cache_nodes` that you can only specify one instance for Redis. In order to create a clustered Redis setup you need to create an `elasticache_replication_group`, you can find the documentation to do that in Terraform [here.](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/elasticache_replication_group.html)